# displaying table with images with PHP

Tags: php

Here's my code :

```
<?php
$items = array();
$images = node_files(request('nid')) ; 
$gallery_cover = db_fetch_row("node_meta","nid='".request('nid')."' AND name='gallery_image'");


foreach ($images as $key => $value)
{
$items[$key]['weight'] = $value['fid'].'_'.$value['weight'] ;
$items[$key]['image'] = '<a href="'.image_url($value['uri']).'" data-lightbox="gallery-image_'.$value['fid'].'">'.image_load($value['uri'],array("class"=>"img-thumbnail","thumbs"=>"small")).'</a>' ;
$items[$key]['title'] = '<span id="title_file_'.$value['fid'].'">'.$value['title'].'</span>' ;

$cover = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:gallery_cover(\"".$value['fid']."\"); return false;' id='gallery_cover_".$value['fid']."' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Top' id='tooltip1'><span class='btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-".(isset($gallery_cover['value']) && $gallery_cover['value']==$value['fid']?'open':'close')."'></span></a>" ; 
$edit = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:update_file(\"".$value['fid']."\"); return false;' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Modifier' id='tooltip1'>".IMG_EDIT."</a>" ; 
$delete = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:delete_added_image(\"".$value['fid'].'_'.$value['weight']."\"); return false;' data-toggle='tooltip' class='data-tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Supprimer' id='tooltip1'>".IMG_DELETE."</a>" ; 

$items[$key]['actions'] = $cover." ".$edit." ".$delete ;    
}
foreach($images as $key => $value)
{
if ($key % 4 == 0)
echo "<div class=\"row\">" ; 
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">" ;
echo "<div class='thumbnail'><img src=".image_url($value['uri'])"/>
    <div class='caption'>
        <h4>".$value['title']."</h4> // <--- HERE THE ERROR SHOW
        <p>$cover $edit $delete</p>
    </div></div>" ;
echo "</div>" ;
}
?>
```

I'm trying to dsiplay 4 images in row with the title and the actions `$cover` `$edit` `$delete` and this code generate errors. Where did I go wrong?
this is the error :

`syntax error, unexpected '"/> ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: you must show your error in your post

Comment: Please copy paste your errors.

Comment: Add the line that syntax error says has, and tell us which line it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You:

- forgot to close the bracket at the very end
- forgot to add a dot in the string concatenation

--

```
foreach($images as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key % 4 == 0)
    echo "<div class=\"row\">" ; 
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">" ;
    // added a dot in the line below (almost at the end)
    echo "<div class='thumbnail'><img src=".image_url($value['uri']) . "/>
        <div class='caption'>
        <h4>".$value['title']."</h4>
        <p>$cover $edit $delete</p>
        </div></div>" ;
    echo "</div>" ;
} // <--- HERE
?>
```

For the future, I advice using some (any) [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), e.g. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) (my favourite) or [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/). They're free open source very powerfull tools. If you can afford you can try with [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) which is, IMHO, the best of those three but not free :)

And also for future sakes, I would advice some other style for HTML outputting in PHP. If you're doing `echo` directly in the loop, why not doing it *outside* the PHP? Like this:

```
foreach($images as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key % 4 == 0)
    echo "<div class=\"row\">" ;

    // let's close the PHP block here
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?= image_url($value['uri']); ?>" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?= $value['title']; ?></h4>
                <p><?= $cover . ' ' . $edit . ' ' . $delete; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <? // let's open PHP block again
}
```

This method has lots of advantages:

- HTML markup is more clear to read (helps you avoid syntax errors)
- IDE will format the markup with the tabs
- IDE will color the HTML syntax
- if you're using CSS classes in the markup, IDE will link them to CSS files, it means it will auto-complete suggested classes when you're editing a CSS file
- if any HTML syntax errors occur, IDE will show them
- you can always inject PHP in the markup thanks to `<?=`. It opens the PHP stream and does the `echo`. It's simply the same as `<? echo`.

Comment: Thanks! That must be it :)